# Maximal number of edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness, graph-isomorphism

> Given a simple graph on 15 vertices consists of several (more than one) isomorphic connected components. What is the maximal possible number of edges in this graph?

I tried by using the bipartite approach and using k complete graph approach but am not able to proceed further. Could you please provide some hints on the approach to be followed for the same?

Comment: I don't quite understand the phrasing of the question.  Are *all* connected components isomorphic to one another?  So, you either have three $5$-vertex components or five $3$-vertex components or fifteen $1$-vertex components?

Comment: If so, then it should be clear that to maximize the number of edges, you maximize the number of edges in each component, which occurs when each component is a complete graph.  There are only three possible graphs then and it should be easy to verify which maximized the total number of edges.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks i followed your approach and am able to get it for three 5-vertex components.